# sparse overdetermined linear system with noise

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I'm trying to solve the problem of global alignment of panorama images (it seems it's called [bundle adjustment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bundle_adjustment)).
We have N images and we can calculate translation(dx,dy) between all pairs of images.(I have simplest case only translation).

[Here also](http://users.soe.ucsc.edu/~davis/panorama/slides/slides/slide011.jpg) proposed method wich I'm trying to implement.
[Here](http://scien.stanford.edu/pages/labsite/2000/ee368/projects2000/project13/global.html) more info.

So we have pairwise relations(homography matrix or translation in simplest case) between images and we want to determine global coordinates of images.
But the problems is that not all pairs are "real", so I need algorithm that robust to noise.

Simple example: we have stripe of images 1-2-3 (no pair between 1-3)
But we compute all pairs 1-2 1-3 2-3 and put them in linear system.

If you don't understand what I mean I can provide more examples.

Comment: Sounds like you're reinventing [Hugin](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/) or similar. What exactly is your question? The docs you mention already suggest least squares, so what are you asking here?

Comment: I'm writing app like http://www.xuvtools.org . I'm asking about method similar to least squares,but which can handle outliers, because of the problems is that not all pairs are "real" (false pairs).

Answer (score 1):

You can do a two-step computation: in the first step you compute the best least squares fit, but then you detect those data points which are farthest from that fit, remove them, and do a second least squares fit. The first fill help you identify outliers, while the second ensures that they have no impact whatsoever on the computed result.

Note that if you were to treat this whole thing as an optimization problem, it would likely be non-convex. You could very well have one set of data points suggesting one position, and another equally strong set of data points suggesting a different position. In that case, either position would be a fine match but the positions in between would be worse in almost any metric. Most optimization methods might therefore get stuck in a local minimum which is not neccessarily a global one.

Comment: "detect those data points which are farthest from that fit"  I don't understand how interpret it in my case.